# Run Two methods Parallel, but 1st method gets data in chunks and 2nd method need to process that data parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, async-await

My process Gets the data through HTTP request and it will get the data in Chunks(100 records at a time). in my case I had 100,000 records.

and then I need to process that data and load it into DB..

MY Current Process..

```
GrabAllRecords()
```

{
  GRAB all 100,000 records(i.e 1000 requests).. its big amount of time. 
  Load into ArrayData
 }

then..
Process Data(ArrayData)
{

}

But I need some thing like this...

START:
step1:
Grab 100 Records load into arraylist..
repeat step1 until it reach 100,000

step2:
process arrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This screams for the producer - consumer design pattern: one producer produces something in its own pace, while one or more consumers wait until something is produced, grab the produced information and process it, possibly leading to new produced output that other consumers might process.

Microsoft has good support for this via Microsoft TPL Dataflow nuget package.
[Implement a Producer-Consumer Dataflow Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also helpful to start: [Walkthrough: Creating a Dataflow Pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228604(v=vs.110).aspx)

The producer produces output in processable units, in your case: chunks. The output will be sent to an object of class BufferBlock< T > , where T is your chunk. Code will be similar to:

```
public class ChunkProducer
{
    private BufferBlock<Chunk> outputBuffer = new BufferBlock<Chunk>;
    // whenever the ChunkProducer produces a chunk it is put in this buffer

    // consumers will need access to this outputbuffer as source of data:
    public ISourceBlock<Chunk> OutputBuffer
           {get {return this.outputBuffer as ISourceBlock<Chunk>;} }

    public async Task ProduceAsync()
    {
         while(someThingsToProcess)
         {
             Chunk chunk = CreateChunk(...);
             await this.outputBuffer.SendAsync(chunk);
         }
         // if here: nothing to process anymore.
         // notify consumers that all output has been produced
         this.outputBuffer.Complete();
    }
```

The efficiency of this can be enhanced by creating the next chunk while the previous one is being sent and await before sending the next chunk. This is a bit out of scope here. More info about this is available on Stackoverflow.

You'll also need a ChunkConsumer. The ChunkConsumer will wait for chunks on the buffer block and process them:

```
public class ChunkConsumer
{
    private readonly ISourceBlock<Chunk> chunkSource;
    // the chunkConsumer will wait for input at this source

    public ChunkConsumer(ISourceBlock<Chunk> chunkSource)
    {
        this.chunkSource = chunkSource
    }

    public async Task ConsumeAsync()
    {
        // wait until there is some data in the buffer
        while (await this.chunkSource.OutputAvailableAsync())
        {
            // get the chunk and process it:
            Chunk chunk = this.chunkSource.Receive()
            ProcessChunk(chunk);
        }
        // if here: chunkSource has been completed. No more data to expect
    }
```

Put it all together:

```
private async Task ProcessAsync()
{
    ChunkProducer producer = new ChunkProducer();
    ChunkConsumer consumer = new ChunkConsumer(producer.OutputBuffer);

    // start a thread for the consumer to consume:
    Task consumeTask = Task.Run( () => consumer.ConsumeAsync());

    // let this thread start producing, and await until it is completed
    await producer.ProduceAsync();
    // if here, I know the producer finished producing
    // wait until the consumer finished consuming:
    await consumeTask;

    // finished, all produced data is consumed.
}
```

Possible enhancements:

- If producing is faster than consuming, consider using multiple consumers listening to the same ISourceBlock. Check TPL to see which of the BufferBlock types can handle multiple listeners
- If producing is slower than consuming, consider using multiple producers producing to the same ITargetBlock. Check which type of buffer block can handle this.
- Consider enabling cancellation using CancellationToken
- If your chunk is not always the same number of records, consider using a batch block: The consumer gets notified if the batch has enough records to process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DataFlow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) library to do something like this:

```
ActionBlock<Record[]> action_block = new ActionBlock<Record[]>(
    x => ConsumeRecords(x),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        //Use one thread to process data.
        //You can increase it if you want
        //That would make sense if you produce the records faster than you consume them
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 
    });

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    action_block.Post(ProduceNext100Records());
}
```

I am assuming that you have a method called `ProduceNext100Records` that produces records (e.g. via web service call) and another method called `ConsumeRecords` that consumes the records.

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer I think is to use Microsoft Reactive Extensions (NuGet "Rx-Main").

Then you can do something like this:

```
var query =
    from records in Get100Records().ToObservable()
    from record in records.ToObservable()
    from result in Observable.Start(() => ProcessRecord(record))
    select new { record, result };

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(
            rr =>
            {
                /* Process each `rr.record`/`rr.result`
                as they are produced */
            },
            () => { /* Run when all completed */ });
```

This will process in parallel and you'll start getting results as soon as the first `ProcessRecord` call is completed.

If you need to stop the processing early you just call `subscription.Dispose()`.